# Package to extract many generic features and summary statistics from images

Tags: image, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I have several thousand large images (10-20mb) from which I am trying to extract various summary statistics. They are currently JPGs, but could be obtained in other formats.

I am looking for a package (in R, Python, Matlab, or other language/software) which can extract many summary statistics from each image. I am not looking to identify the objects in the image, but would like to extract as much data about the image as possible (spatial correlation of pixels, summary statistics on edginess, summary statistics on color, ect). Ideally, I want to extract statistics on the visual, statistical, transform coefficient, and algebraic features.

I am aware of some simple commands in R's "raster" package and in matlab, but was hoping for a package, API, or software which provides a more complete solution.

Googling and other responses on the site pointed me towards OpenCV. Is this the right tool for my needs? If I should be using OpenCV, is there a specific batch of algorithms I should be working with?